# XML file reading when item is nested in same bracket

Tags: javascript, xml

I have this code in a Javascript function that reads an XML file:

```
var title = $(this).children('Title').text();
```

This works for this XML code

```
<Title>
Nice long title
</Title>
```

In the same XML file I have information nested within the brackets like this:

```
<ProductSearch>

 <Products totalResultsAvailable="0" firstResultPosition="1" totalResultsReturned="0" searchOperator="or"/>

</ProductSearch>
```

What code do I require to extract the totalResultsAvailable integer? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var totalResultsAvailable = $(this).children('ProductSearch').children('Products').getAttribute("totalResultsAvailable");
```

Comment: I can't get that to work, are you sure this is the correct syntax?

Comment: No errors but my feed is not being displayed at all using this. I shall probably have to open another question about calling various levels of the XML tree as this seems to be the issue now. I shall come back and accept this answer when I know it works though, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, I completely rewrote the code in the end but have since tested your code and it does work, so accepting your answer. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @Sara44, sorry I didn't help you better though, glad you got it working